# How to delete a component in RTC?

Tags: eclipse, rtc, alm

I have created a stream and a component; and added the same component to the stream.
But now I want to delete the component. Is it possible to delete ?

I know I can remove the component from stream, but since this component is 
of no use I want to delete it.

Please let me know if there is any possibility to delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible today (2014, RTC5+)

The [story 163568](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=163568) (you need a free jazz.net account to see it) tracks that feature request since April 2011.

What you can do is change its ownership, either to your account, or make it changed to the account of an RTC admin.

Once the component is owned by a person (as opposed to owned by a project area or a team area), it does becomes "invisible" for the other people member of the project area.

As mentioned [in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/74066/permanently-remove-a-component-from-rtc):

> - You can remove the component from the stream,
> - you can rename it and use it for something later or
> - you can change the owner to a garbage collector owner, so that it does not show in the UI.

That same thread suggests though:

> Well, there IS a way to clean this up..
>
> - **Create a new personal workspace (some admin user not in normal projects)**
> - In the workspace editor page, add the specific component names to the new workspace.
> - Now,  click on each component that you want to hide, and select
>     `Change Owner`, making them owned by the same person as owns the workspace, (instead of the project being the component owner).
>     Note that you do not get a 'chance' to back out of this change. Even before you save the workspace.
> - Save the workspace editor window
>
> The components are not deleted but they no longer displayed for anyone. (other than the owner)
>   I also made the personal  workspace private.